# Set M-values as distance: Multipart M-values are set in descending order

Tags: arcgis-pro, line, vertices, linear-referencing, m-values

I have a multipart polyline in an ArcGIS Pro 2.9.2 FGDB feature class (NAD83 UTM):

[image]

I can set the M-values to the cumulative distance of the line by using the **Set As Distance** tool (setting "Starting M" to zero):

[image]

That works as expected. Part #2's M-values are in the correct order (ascending).

[image]

However, if I do a different test, the results are unexpected:

- [Drop the measures.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCsnL.png)
- Try a slightly different feature:

  Change the X-coordinate of part #1, vertex 2...from 130 meters to 135 meters.
- Re-do the test:

  Set the M-values to the cumulative distance of the line by using the **Set As Distance** tool (setting "Starting M" to zero).

Now, part #2's M-values are in the **in**correct order (descending):

[image]

---

Why are the M-values in the **in**correct order? (descending)

I would expect the M-value order to be the same as the vertex index's order (ascending).

Comment: I would fire this off to ESRI support, looks like a bug.

Comment: @Hornbydd - Esri confirmed it's a defect: `BUG-000148390`.

Comment: Good! Well done, rattle that cage! Rage against the machine and all that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esri says a defect: BUG-000148390.